# RegEx do not match

Tags: python, regex

string:

"Btw-nummer: NL855162508B01
NL855162508B02
"

```
Regex code used:

(^((?!NL855162508B01).))([A-Za-z]{2}\d{9}[A-Za-z]\d{2})
```

Regex do not match:
NL855162508B01

But do match:
NL855162508B02

As seen in this Regexr I have used:
https://regexr.com/5im28

Desired behavior:
match NL855162508B02

Can you guys help?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Comment: It think you are looking for `\b(?!NL855162508B01)[A-Za-z]{2}\d{9}[A-Za-z]\d{2}\b` https://regex101.com/r/1e6hgb/1

Comment: sorry Matt, edited.

Comment: Thank you Fourth Bird! You're a legend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there, but this part `(?!NL855162508B01).` first matches any character except a newline due to the `.`

You are using 3 capturing groups, which can all be omitted if you need a match only.

To also match the string when it is not directly at the start, you can omit the anchor `^` and use word boundaries `\b`

```
\b(?!NL855162508B01\b)[A-Za-z]{2}\d{9}[A-Za-z]\d{2}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2gYyFI/1)